# How to make UI in android for different devices

Tags: android, imageview

I'm fresher in Android & Coding. I have a task to design a popular game dots and boxes, for references   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_and_Boxes .  In this I have 7X7 cicles and used imageview to display all the stuff. My problem is how to design for multiple devices which looks as designed.

Comment: Please refer this link for your solution https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: your user name is GOOD

Comment: @iAndroid i guess your approach is only useful for visualizing data or for navigating. In this case, a game has to be developped where normally no such navigation or data visualization is implemented or needed.

Comment: @DerAdler kindly for your information if you develop game in android native or any third party library you need to give appropriate resource as per device resolution.I suggested reference link for it.Below answer also as per link

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tool that lets you turn one image into multiple images for different screen densities: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

There a few options there for generating the images, i use the [Generic icons](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html) option since it allows an option for resizing the image.

if you use the generic option then:

1. **Source:** click image and upload the image (the circle for example).
2. **Size and Padding:** the defaults for size and padding are usually good enough.
3. **Color:** defaults to blue just move the seekbar to the far left in order to use the original color of the uploaded image.
4. **Name and Download:** at the bottom of the page you can rename the image see a preview and download as a zip.
5. **Import:** in the zipped file will be a res folder already structured properly by drawable densities and ready for you to just drag and drop into you /src/main folder.

**P.S.** Thank you to the person that made this tool your a genius and a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use the unit **dp** for defining measurements. In addition to that, you have to define several values folders, where you define dimensions for scaling tablets or phones. E.g. define two values folders like:

```
values-large
values-xlarge
```

Now define a dimen.xml file inside this folders, where you can put your measurements in (unit dp) for the corresponding screensize. Define a measurement like this:

```
 <dimen name="value1">17dp</dimen>
```

Then embedd this sizes in your layout xml, like:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/value1"
```

Depending on the screensize, the system will load the correct measurements from this folders, e.g. if you have a screen size large only the defined values in folder values-large will be loaded. So instead of creating different layouts, define different measurements that can be loaded by the system automatically. For more information about this, also have a look at https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html